# Convert 500000 seconds to HH:MM:SS

Tags: sas

I'm attempting to convert a bunch of columns which contain seconds to HH:MM:SS. Most entries are within a 24 hour period such as 78000 seconds.
For these I have used format time10. Which gives 21 hours and 42 minutes in this case.

However when I have something like 528846 seconds, sas returns its fine when I open the data set, however when I proc export:

```
Proc export data = myset
Outfile =mylocation\about.xlsx
Dbms=excel2000 replace;
Sheet="mysheet";
Run;
```

When I open the excel output my value shows as 00/01/1900 02:54:06. I've tried use the date formats in excel but cant get it do display as the 146:54:06 (528846 seconds to hours, mins and secs)

Any suggestions pls?

Comment: How to display seconds in that style is something you need to do in the EXCEL document.  Time values in SAS are seconds.  Did you try just attaching the TIME format to the variable so that PROC EXPORT will try to tell Excel to format it as a time value?

Comment: I would recommend using ODS if you could, that gives you a little more control over the display, I'm confused why you're using DBMS=excel2000 for an XLSX file. Have you tried using PUT() to convert it to a character and see how Excel deals with that?

Comment: FYI - I removed the SQL tag as it really doesn't apply here at all IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the value as a number in EXCEL?  If not then convert it to a string in that style in your SAS dataset before exporting it.

```
data for_export ;
  set myset ;
  time_string = put(time_var,time12.);
run;
proc export data=for_export file='mylocation\about.xlsx' dbms=xlsx replace;
  sheet="mysheet";
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel will display hours > 24 if you use custom format `[h]:mm:ss`.

You can coerce output to use a custom format by using a Proc that allows ODS styling where in the style attribute setting `tagattr="format:'[h]:mm:ss'"` can be used.

**Sample data (`time10.`)**

```
data have;
  format elapsed time10.;
  input elapsed @@; datalines;
78000 86399 86400 86401 528846
;
```

[image]

**Fix: Use ODS style attribute `tagattr`**

```
ods excel file='try-2.xlsx';

proc print noobs label data=have;
  var elapsed / style=[tagattr="format:'[h]:mm:ss'"];
run;

ods excel close;
```

[image]

**Problem: Proc EXPORT**

```
proc export data=have replace outfile='try-1.xlsx' dbms=xlsx;
  sheet="My Sheet";
run;
options noxwait noxsync xmin;
%sysexec start "Preview" try-1.xlsx;
```

The `EXPORT` `DBMS=XLSX` engine outputs SAS `time10.` formatted data values as cells with Excel custom format `h:mm`.  *(Note: Output made with SAS 9.4 M6)*

[image]

Comment: This worked a charm Richard. Also tried  Toms solution which also worked but would have introduced 'sum' calculation restrictions in excel, thanks all.